# Erro ao tentar estabelecer conexão entre SQL Server 2014 e Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Estou tendo problemas para realizar a conexão do Visual Studio 2010 [c#] com o Sql server 2014. Segui alguns tutoriais mas não tive sucesso.

[image]

Porque está acontecendo tal erro?

Comment: Já viste se o serviço "SQL Server Browser Service" está activo?

Comment: Por favor, poste também a parte do seu código em que você se conecta com o banco

Comment: Poste a sua ConnectionString.

Comment: Estava seguindo este tutorial, criei o projeto mas quando fui  adicionar o Service-based Database aconteceu o erro. Segue tutorial:[link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms233763%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Está em execução.

Comment: Não cheguei a configurar uma connection String, pois ainda não vi como fazer..

Comment: Pode ser por causa da firewall: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

ou por não estar configurado para aceitar ligações externas: http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote.aspx

Comment: Saberiam me informar alguma versão para download do Sql Server em uma versão anterior, utilizo Windows 8 x64 e sempre que tento instalar outra versão ocorre erro de compatibilidade.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Desativar o firewall resolve? Meu inglês não está ajudando..

Comment: Experimentaste desativar o firewall? Que protocolos de comunicação do SQL Server tens ativos - memory, pipes, tcp?

Comment: shared memory, tcp/ip, named pipes, via

Comment: Já liberou a porta 1433?

Comment: @Pegasus olha esse tutorial de como configurar a porta http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote.aspx

Comment: Acabo de encontrar a resposta no MSDN. Segue link para quem interessar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8db82f0-50ed-4531-9209-940006ed34cb(v=sql.110)#connect

Comment: Consegui resolver. Segue o mesmo link em português: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms345332.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Pegasus, tente isso;

1. Certifique-se de que o nome da instância está correto. (EX: NomeInstancia\NomeBanco)
2. Certifique-se que a máquina usada como servidor está acessível. (Você pode usar o ping no prompt de comando para verificar se a máquina está ligada)
3. Certifique-se de que o SQL Server está em execução no servidor. (Se possível vá ao servidor e tente se conectar através do SQL Server Managment Studio com suas credenciais)
4. Se o firewall estiver habilitado no servidor, você precisará adicionar uma permissão para o sqlbrowser.exe e/ou porta UDP 1434 em exceção.

Fonte: http://goo.gl/hDnMXZ

Answer (score 1):

Erro 26 é porque o servidor SQL não está em execução. Ou seja, ta desligado. Isso é normal de acontecer quando se reinicializa a máquina. Pra resolver é fácil. Vá no menu iniciar, procure por Microsoft SQL Server Versão(2008,2012,2014) clique e  procure por Ferramentas de Configuração, depois clique em SQL Server Configuration Manager. Ao clicar ele vai uma janela e ai vai vá em  Serviços do SQL Server e procurar por SQL Server(SQLEXpress) dai é só clicar duas vezes e pronto, o server ta up ! Espero ter ajudado !